# Why can't I use maxLength in input?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I get an Error when I add maxLength to input,Invalid DOM property `maxlength`. Did you mean `maxLength`?https://codesandbox.io/s/nkz2kwl7y0

Comment: Did you try changing the l to uppercase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because in jsx html attributes are in `camelCase` Please check [supported html attributes](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes) in reactjs

Answer (score 0):

Class names and attributes in **reactjs** are `camelCased`. You should use `maxLength` instead of `maxlength`

Comment: You are correct, attribute and properties in jsx and tsx are camel Case. Classes and components are PascalCase though.